# Merging different columns from different data frames in R

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames:

dataframe 1:

```
Class    Total       AC
A        1000        0.6
A        965         0.34
B        1025        0.9
B        1002        0.37
B        684         0.55
C        896         0.77
C        927         0.86
C        1000        0.61
C        955         0.69
```

dataframe 2:

```
Class    Total       Coverage
A        925         0.6
A        744         0.94
A        1000        0.38
B        581         0.68
B        488         0.25
B        698         0.66
C        1020        0.33
C        845         0.18
C        1555        0.66
```

What I want is to only take the `AC` value for the first two rows for each class from the dataframe 2 and also the `Coverage` value from the first two rows for the same class from the dataframe 1 and combine them together as the following:

```
Class    AC         Coverage
A        0.6         0.6
A        0.34        0.94
B        0.9         0.68
B        0.37        0.25
C        0.77        0.33
C        0.86        0.18
```

Note that it is always guaranteed that there are at least two rows for each class in both data frames.

Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr` -

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(rn %in% 1:2) %>%
  inner_join(
    df2 %>%
    group_by(Class) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(rn %in% 1:2),
    by = c("Class", "rn")
  ) %>%      
  select(Class, AC, Coverage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

Merge the two data frames together first.

```
df <- merge(df1$AC, df2$Coverage, by = "Class")
```

Secondly `slice` the top two results from each group within a Class:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
      group_by(Class) %>%
      slice(2)
```